# ADC Multiple Channel without using DMA

Tags: stm32, adc, c, interrupts, keil

below i give my code. here i using 2 ADC Channel and i getting first ADC channel value only. i need to read both ADC channel value.

```
#include<stm32f10x.h>

int flag=0;
int Channel0Data=0;
int Channel1Data=0;

void delay(unsigned int T)
{
    while(T--);
}

void ADC1_2_IRQHandler(void);

void ADCInitialize()
{
    RCC->APB2ENR|= 0x00000200;  //ADC 1 interface clock enable
    RCC->APB2ENR|= 0x00000004;  //I/O port A clock is Enable
    RCC->CFGR|=0x00008000;  //  ADC prescaler /PCLK2 divided by 6(72MHZ/6=12MHZ)
    
    GPIOA->CRL|=0x00000000;  //All GPIO_A PIN SELECTED AS ANALOG INPUT
    
    ADC1->CR1|=(1<<8);  //Scan mode enable
    
    ADC1->CR2|=0x00000003;  //  Enable ADC and to start conversion & Continuous conversion mode
    delay(1);
    ADC1->CR2|=0x00000001;  //  Enable ADC and to start conversion
    delay(1);
    ADC1->CR2|=0x00000004;  // ENABLE CALIBRATION
    while(ADC1->CR2 & 0x00000004);
    
    ADC1->SMPR2|=0x00000037;   //  SELECT SAMPLE TIME AS 71.5 cycles & 239.5 cycles
    ADC1->SQR1|=(1<<20);   //  SELECT THE 2_CONVERSIONS
    //ADC1->SQR3|=0x00000007;   //  SELECT THE CHANNEL
    
}


void ADCSetInterruptMode()
{
    ADC1->CR1|=(1<<5);  //Interrupt enable for EOC
    NVIC_EnableIRQ(ADC1_2_IRQn);  //Enable that interrupt int the NVIC
    NVIC_SetPriority(ADC1_2_IRQn, 0);
}

void ADCChannelSelect(int Channel)
{
    ADC1->SQR3|=(Channel<<0);
}

int main()
{
    ADCInitialize();
    ADCSetInterruptMode();
    ADCChannelSelect(0);
    ADCChannelSelect(1);
    ADC1->CR2|=0x00000001;
    
    while(1)
    {
        
    }
}

void ADC1_2_IRQHandler(void)
{
    if(flag==2)
    {
        flag=0;
    }
    if(flag==0)
    {
        Channel0Data=ADC1->DR;
    }
    if(flag==1)
    {
        Channel1Data=ADC1->DR;
    }
    flag++;
}
```

Comment: "Enable ADC and to start conversion & Continuous conversion mode" then "Enable ADC and to start conversion". This doesn't make much sense. The whole point of continuous conversion is that you don't have to kick the ADC manually to start each conversion, but can instead just grab a value "on the fly".

Comment: Thank you for your comment. and I'm currently working with ADC Multiple channel using interrupt mode without using DMA. i getting only one adc value and i cannot getting second adc value. i don't know where i mistake. if you know help me.

Comment: I don't know this ADC peripheral but often when you have multichannel there is only one actual ADC circuit and the channels are scheduled to it sequentially by the ADC hardware. If you have continuous conversion it probably just keeps doing this automatically, but if you stop it and trigger the conversion manually, you might only get one single conversion from the channel that was currently accessed. But you really have to read the manual to study these things - I'm just speculating here based on my experience of other multichannel SA ADC on other MCUs.

Comment: Thank you for your comment

Answer (score 1):

I am using this code to switch between channels in the adc, I hope can help you:

```
   float AdcRead(uint32_t canal, uint8_t numAverage){
        ADC_ChannelConfTypeDef cConfig = {0};
        cConfig.Channel = canal;
        cConfig.Rank = 1;
        cConfig.SamplingTime = ADC_SAMPLETIME_3CYCLES;
          if (HAL_ADC_ConfigChannel(&hadc1, &cConfig) != HAL_OK)
          {
            Error_Handler();
          }
    
        uint32_t adcr = 0;
    
        for(uint8_t i=0; i<numAverage; i++){
            HAL_ADC_Start(&hadc1);
            HAL_ADC_PollForConversion(&hadc1, 1);
            adcr += HAL_ADC_GetValue(&hadc1);
        }
        //HAL_ADC_Stop(&hadc1);
    
        return (float)adcr/(float)numAverage;
    }
```